# How to unescape '&' in Jade

Tags: pug

Finding some difficulty rendering out '&' using the Jade engine. 
I need to make a call to Google Maps using the following string:
`script(type='text/javascript', src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE')`

But this will be rendered in Jade as: 
`src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE`

Answer (score 11):

Still according to https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/198 it is now possible to write:

```
script(type='text/javascript', src!='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE')
```

Note the `!=` for the `src` argument; thus its content is not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still need an workaround to this; they can read [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/198).

So, my workaround to this is just to use plain script tags.  Here's the content for the jade file.

```
!!!
html
head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/test.css')
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>

    script(src='/javascripts/test.js')

body
    button(onclick='initialize()') Click Me!
    div#map_canvas
```

Answer (score -3):

`&amp;` is how you represent "An ampersand" in HTML. `&` means "Start of a character reference".

Your current output is correct and will work (unless something *else* is wrong with it). You are trying to produce invalid code that depends on browsers to perform error recovery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just made some changes to the original question. I need to call Google map using "&", and not "&Amp;". The current output is not recognized by Google.

Comment: @ngzhongcai — You **are** calling Google Maps with `&`. `&amp;` is how you tell the browser to put an `&` character somewhere.

Comment: In the end I din use the jade syntax... <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE"></script>

Comment: I also got the same problem. But unfortunately I can not replace with tag, I need to use attribute value computed. No solution yet.

Comment: Angular makes heavy use of `&` for it's templating sytnax